# Importing a tsv file into dynamoDB

Tags: dataset, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dataset, got from the registry of open data on AWS. 
[This](https://registry.opendata.aws/amazon-reviews/) is the link of my data set. I want to import this data set into a DynamoDb table, but I don't know how to do it

I tried to use data Pipeline, from S3 bucket to dynamoDB but it didn't work

> at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1836)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:169) Caused
>   by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected ':' at
>   line 1 column 20 at
>   com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1505) at
>   com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:519) at
>   com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:414) at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
>   at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
>   at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:187)
>   at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
>   at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803) ... 15 more Exception
>   in thread "main" java.io.

I have this error and I don't know how to fix it.
than I downloaded the file locally but I can't import it into my table in dynamoDb

There is no code for the moment, all i do is configuration

I'm expecting to have the data set into my table, but unfortunately I couldn't reach my goal

Answer (score 0):

i finally converted the TSV file to a CSV file then to a Json file using a python script. 
with a Json file it's much easier